# Lavatory bubbling

Tags: bathroom, basement

My house has 3 bathrooms:  basement, main floor, second floor.  After someone takes a shower/bath or flushes in the basement bathroom, the main floor lavatory starts to bubble.  Should I call a plumber or a cesspool company.

Comment: Do you have a cesspool? Please add more details about the type system you are connected to and how it is connected.

Comment: Depends if by "bubbling" you mean water backing up or just gas bubbles. If it's air/gas bubbling out, check the vent stack. Otherwise, you have septic tank/cesspool issues.

Comment: Sounds like a plugged vent to me is the water level also moving around? Over the years I have found vents plugged with everything from tree leaves to dead squirrels and birds.